# Alguien que me pueda brindar su ayuda

Tags: php

```
<?php $uno = 0;
 $cadena = "100100100100";
 $uno += $cadena;
 echo $uno;
?>
```

necesito hacer una suma de 100 en 100

Comment: Necesitamos más detalles de qué es ese código que pusiste allí. ¿Quieres extraer los números 100 de la cadena y luego sumarlos? Y por favor, cambia el título a algo puntual, ¿qué es exactamente lo que necesitas? Piensa en eso y colócalo como título.

Answer (score 3):

Si te refieres a lo que hay dentro de $uno, una solución sería separar los cien que aparecen dentro del string y convertirlo en array con **str_split**.

Podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$uno = "100100100100";
$arr = str_split($uno, 3);
print_r($arr);

$resultado = 0;

foreach ($arr as $valor){
$resultado = $resultado + $valor;
}

echo "El resultado es: $resultado";

?>
```

La salida debería arrojar lo siguiente para este caso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaré atenta a actualizaciones.

Answer (score 3):

En caso de que interese únicamente el resultado final, hay una solución de una sola línea, combinando [**`str_split()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php) con [**`array_sum()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php), que consistiría en esto:

```
$resultado=array_sum(str_split($uno, 3));
```

Ejemplo:

```
$uno = "100100100100";
$resultado=array_sum(str_split($uno, 3));
echo $resultado;
```

Salida:

```
400
```